# A single word meaning deep love of reading

Tags: single-word-requests

Not bibliophile, or really anything "biblio-" because that means a love of books, which might mean a collector or someone who loves the books themselves, but not necessarily their content.  Also, not words like bookworm, because they refer to the person who loves reading, whereas I'd like a word that describes the act or state of loving to read.

Comment: If we go from Latin, _lectiophilia_ would fit. Though it can only qualify as a nonce word for now but it can become a neologism perhaps.

Comment: @ermanen: couldn't a *lectiophile* be someone with a deep love of bed? Like many teenagers.

Comment: "Lectio" means reading in Latin.

Comment: Actually, "-philia" is from Greek (philo - loving), so I'd go with "anagnosephilia". hth.

Comment: I assume "bookworm" conveys the behavior but fails to convey the emotion you are trying to convey...

Comment: @jules: Just as a note: Words ending with -philia or -phile does not have to have a Greek root before the suffix part (there are words of Latin origin that uses this suffix). The suffix has a history in Latin language also. (but the origin is Ancient Greek)

Comment: The reason bookworm (and actually, all of the suggestions, which nonetheless are all excellent) doesn't work is because it describes A PERSON (caps for emphasis, not tone) who loves to read.  I am looking for THE STATE of loving to read.  The definition of this word should be: "the love of reading" or "a great affinity for reading."  Bookworm also could convey a love of knowledge, but not actually gaining enjoyment from the act of reading itself.  I honestly don't know if there is a word with this meaning...it seems like there really should be, though.

Comment: _Lectiophilia_ would be the state (the love of reading), not the person. _Lectiophile_ would be the person. I did not give as an answer because it is not a word (yet). I could give an answer if I could find a back-up at least from online sources.

Answer (score 9):

**Bibliophily** is the fondness or love for books or **reading**

&

describing someone who likes to read as having:

> **[Ballycumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballycumber#Ballycumber_in_literature)** n. One of the six half-read books lying somewhere in your bed.
>   - (1983) coined by Douglas Adams and John Lloyd.

&

> **[Librocubicularist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/librocubicularist)** (plural librocubicularists). (rare) A person who reads in bed.

&

> **[Omnilegent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnilegent)** reading or having read everything; having encyclopedic curiosity and knowledge: *no historians have been more
>   omnilegent, more careful of the document* - George Saintsbury

Comment: All excellent, but still looking for a word that doesn't indicate a PERSON (CAPS for emphasis, I'm not yelling, I promise), but rather just the love itself (so your second and your last come closest).  Thanks though, these are quite good.

Comment: I found a wordy Latin quote from 1344 to describe the love of reading -it was called "love of reading".  Does your word need to be in English?

Comment: @ThirdNews I don't know if you still check this and maybe on this SE it's not appreciated but personally I'd love to see that quote. But I'm fascinating with language in general - philology, logophile, bibliophile, bibliomane/bibliomaniac (I'm really addicted to buying books...) and etymology too of course. The quote sounds interesting (if you even remember where it was)! Oh and wonderful post. Rare words are a delight and I'm saving these three you refer to in my file I keep of interesting words. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 9):

There is the word ***[bookish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bookish)***:

> fond of reading; studious

and ***bookishness*** for the fondness of reading:

> the quality or condition of being bookish

The word has other connotations as well but I think this word is the closest single word you can get for this meaning.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, *lectiophilia* would be a suitable neologism for the love of reading if we follow the path of bibliophilia (and such words suffixed with -philia). *Lectio* means reading in Latin. In the end, it can always be used as a nonce word.

Answer (score 4):

> **[bibliophagist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bibliophagist)** (plural *bibliophagists*)
>
> (rare) A bibliophage; one who loves to read books.

The term is also listed in *[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bibliophagist)* and *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliophagist)*

Comment: I don’t dispute your source, but *biblio**phage*** sounds like someone who literally (as opposed to metaphorically) devours books. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about the word ["**bookaholic**"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bookaholic)? It is an informal word defined as:

> A habitual and prolific reader; a compulsive book buyer.

Answer (score 1):

Bookworm (informal) ; *noun*

: a person unusually devoted to reading and study (Merriam-Webster online)

: a person who reads a lot (Cambridge dictionary online)

*The librarian of former times was almost invariably a bookworm*

Comment: No; OP had already mentioned and discounted this.

Answer (score 1):

Logophile (like myself).

> [Definition by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logophile):
> *noun*
>
> A lover of words.

Comment: Hi Elisheva, welcome to EL&U. I've [edit]ed your answer to include a published source and link for the definition you provided, but you should do this yourself in future answers. An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Note that your post has been flagged for possible deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**" and is still lacking a solid explanation on why *logophile* represents "a deep love of reading" rather than, say, a crossword enthusiast. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: A lover of words may be interested in spoken rather than written word

Comment: That's not the same thing though. I'm a logophile, a bibliophile and a bibliomane (bibliomaniac) and even get stuck in the dictionary (and have since I was a child) but I wouldn't identify any of those as loving to read per se. Still I can see how it could be interpreted that way. @nnnnnn Yes and then you also have philology/philologists to consider.

Answer (score 0):

lectiophile - *Latin* reading lover

Answer (score 0):

The Latin for "I read" is lego, so I suggest legophilia  (yes, why not combine Latin and Greek?)

Comment: If it can be considered a word (and I suspect it's not in OED), then it seems to be used (rarely) in connection with the building blocks.

Comment: Sounds to me like a love of building things out of Legos.

Comment: @HotLicks That's what I thought of and it's what made me laugh out loud. Brilliant answer even if it has other meanings that's easy to think of!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not. There's just 'Lego' and 'Leg over' but not what's suggested. Still that's a good analogy.